# Prove or disprove existence of a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am thinking about the following problem:

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be compact Hausdorff topological spaces, such that $X$ is not homeomorphic to $Y$. Is it true, that $X\times Z$ is not homeomorphic to $Y \times Z$?

My guess is the answer yes. However my professor told me the following:

"In general topology every statement either has a trivial proof or a counterexample".

According to his wisdom the statement should be false, since I do not have a trivial proof. Ok, now about my attempts:

According to A.N. Kolmogorov if you do not know how to solve the problem, you should try both to prove and disprove it.

What should I do to prove it? Well, the only thing that come to my mind is the following: I should construct a map between spaces and prove that the map is homeomorphism. It looks absolutely hopeless - I do not know anything positive about $X$ and $Y$, I know only one negative thing.

Disproving this fact in principle does not look hopeless - I have to construct a counterexample. How should I do that? I have no idea. I do not know any properties that can be lost when taking direct products. I do not know almost anything about properties that will survive (I know that direct product of compact spaces is compact). I would be nice if you mention another properties that will survive.

Can you give me a hint or something more?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about taking $X$, $Y$ to be discrete spaces and $Z$ a Cantor set?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please give a hint why you chose that particular $Z$ (what topological properties of $Z$ are important  ) and how to construct a homeomorphism between $X \times Z$ and $Y \times Z$?

Comment: One way of thinking about the Cantor set is as $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\{0,1\}$. Obviously then it can be expressed as a finite direct product in infinitely many ways.

Comment: Is it an infinite product of a set with two elements? If so what do you mean by "finite direct" product? Doesn't finite direct product of finite sets have to be finite? Sorry for confusion.

Comment: To the proposer:  If $X$ is finite and discrete with $n$ members then $X\times Z$ is the topological sum of $n$ copies of X.  The Cantor set $C$ is homeomorphic to the top'l sum of $n$ members of itself.  So let $X=\{1,2\}$ be discrete and $Y=\{1\} $.

Comment: To DanielWainfleet: Thanks, I 100% sure that this answer is correct, but I do not get it myself still. Why $Z$ is homeomorphic to the topological sum of two copies of itself? How to see it? Can you please provide a hint or reference?

Comment: @Hedgehog The usual Cantor set $C$ in $[0,1]$ falls into two disjoint closed subsets, got by applying the functions $x\mapsto x/3$ and $x\mapsto (x+2)/3$ to $C$.

Comment: To  Lord Shark the Unknown: Thanks. I guess I have to ask another specific  question about Cantor set (if I not figure out everything myself) and this question is answered anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could also take $X$ and $Y$ discrete spaces consisting of one respectively two points. Clearly not homeomorphic, but if $Z$ is countable and discrete (e.g. $Z = \mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{R}$), then $X\times Z$ and $Y \times Z$ are both discrete and countable and as such homeomorphic.

Comment: That $Z$ isn't compact.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I didn't read the question well enough. Then your seemingly more complicated solution is of course better.

Comment: To correct this let $Z$ be a compact Hausdorff space  that is homeomorphic  to the topological sum of two copies of itself, e.g. let $Z$ be the Cantor set.